# Show google calendar within my ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, google-calendar-api, asp.net-core-2.2

I just want that my users have the possibility to **access their (not my!) google calendar** within my application. I do NOT need any data from their google calendar. So first i tried with just a simple iframe, but google blocked this.

I tried this: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js. It's working, but I just can access the data from the google calendar, but I do NOT have the calendar view..

So what is the **easiest way to show the google calendar of the user**?

Comment: What if the person your trying to do this with doesn't want you to show their calendar to them? It's a private thing, what makes you think google would just allow you to popup someones private calendar, seemingly on your web page? Can you see how this could be exploited by malicious individuals? The API is designed to allow you to send and receive specific pieces of information (that the user has authorised)

Comment: Do you know the application FRANZ? It's a dekstop application and there the google calendar is also integrated, like I want it. It just shows the website of google calendar and then I can login on the website..

Comment: I'd imagine "FRANZ" (no I've never heard of it) queries the data out of google and renders it back to you itself.

Comment: I don't think so, because the page looks EXACTLY like the website.. I'm not sure, maybe it's working because it's a desktop application using a webview?

Comment: Possibly. A desktop app could also be a browser. So it could just be browsing to the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into how the X-Frame-Options header works.  Google Calendar responds to requests for a calendar in two possible ways:

1. If the calendar in question is marked Public, the response is returned with no "X-Frame-Options" header, and thus you can render it in your site.
2. If the calendar in question is not marked as Public, the response includes the "X-Frame-Options" header with a value set to DENY.  According to the HTTP specification, this means that you are not allowed to show the response inside an IFrame, and nothing you can do is going to change that assuming you're using standards-based browsers.

The other application you mentioned likely includes a Web Browser control, and thus is rendering the calendar directly, meaning that the frame options don't impact it, but there's not a good way to simulate that inside a browser (again, part of the HTTP spec, and intended).

Your best option here if you really want to be able to show them their calendar is to consume the data from the API endpoint you mention and then produce your own view of it.